# Keep a fixed bottom navigation view/Tablayout when action bar is hiding/showing

Tags: android, animation, android-actionbar, android-tablayout, bottomnavigationview

I would like to reproduce the same behavior as the 2017 Youtube menu.

Everything works fine but there is a quick animation of the bottom navigation view when the action bar is hiding/showing (quick slide up/down). I want to keep a fixed navigation view who's not affected by action bar animation show/hide.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: Any solution for this?